# how to extract the data from repeated nodes from xml in C#

Tags: xml

I have an XML where there are repeated nodes .Is it possible to get the data from all the nodes in C#?

a> Info1 /a>

a> Info2 /a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(Path);

parentNodes = doc1.Descendants("a")
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .ToList();

The list contains "Info1","Info2"